# Setting Django CSRF Cookie

Tags: django, reactjs, fetch, csrf

I'm using React as front and Django as back. Httprequest fails, prompting that the CSRF Cookie is not set. I have followed [the django docs,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/)I have this code:

```
var jQuery = require("jquery");
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

let header = new Headers({
  "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
  "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH"
});
```

Using `console.log(getCookie("csrftoken"));` prints *null*, which leads me to believe that Django is not setting the cookie.

My middleware looks like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Early in development I used this view for testing:

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def token(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['GET'])
```

This works well, but it does not feel very clean to call this everytime the user uses the website.

The view that is failing:

```
def loginView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = json.loads(request.body.decode())['username']
        password = json.loads(request.body.decode())['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse(status=200) #OK
        else:
            return HttpResponse(status=401) #DENIED
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])
```

I am using a few more views, and they also fail if I do not provide a CSRF key.

Comment: can you show us the actual View you are using??? the function `token` is not the actual view right???

Comment: I added the view I have been testing with, but if I understand correctly CSRF is checked at every view.

Comment: Official docs say: if CSRF_USE_SESSIONS is True (default False) django store the CSRF token in the user’s session instead of in a cookie. It requires the use of django.contrib.sessions.

Have you changed the parameter??? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#csrf-use-sessions

Comment: I had! Now I am able to print the csrf key to the console, but django still says the CSRF cookie is not set.

Comment: I had a similar issue and passed 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(), in my jquery data to solve it.

Comment: @Ashish Where would I add this? Sorry but I'm quite new to javascript

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment. I passed on the value of csrf token via my jquery as below. May be you can try the same.

```
function getDetail(e){

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/result/",
      data: {
            'search': $(this).text(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
      },
      dataType:'html',
      success: function(data) {
          # Do other stuff
      },
  });

};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.

Comment: Sadly the developer who started the project choose to use fetch instead of ajax, so Im having a hard time using your code.

Comment: When is the csrf key provided? This confuses me.
My site first page is only a log in page, so there is not view that could do ensure_csrf. And I cannot find any cookies at all in the page.

Comment: If your react is a separate app then you can explicitly set the CSRF using `@ensure_csrf_cookie` attribute.